# rvm will not update ruby, cant install multiple gems with brew - OS X Mountain Lion

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm, osx-mountain-lion

I am using the latest GCC installer (https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer/downloads) (which I understand means I do not require Xcode command line tools), latest Homebrew, latest RVM

My machine will not update the ruby version. Having tried to uninstall and reinstall I am back at ruby version ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin12.0] and now cannot get it back to 1.9.3.

This all stemmed from not being able to install the thinclient gem because of a problem with eventmachine.

The makelog output trying to install 1.9.3 is as follows:

```
ld: library not found for -lssl
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [../../../.ext/x86_64-darwin12.2.0/digest/md5.bundle] Error 1
make[1]: *** [ext/digest/md5/all] Error 2
make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
```

I think this is an issue with my paths, it cannot find the libraries. For example, if I try

```
brew install postgresql
```

I get an error saying it cannot find crypto libraries, even though I have them in usr/lib

My .bash_profile is as follows:

```
function parse_git_branch () {
   git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}
RED="\[\033[0;31m\]"
YELLOW="\[\033[0;33m\]"
GREEN="\[\033[0;32m\]"
NO_COLOUR="\[\033[0m\]"

PS1="$NO_COLOUR\u@iMac$NO_COLOUR:\w$YELLOW\$(parse_git_branch)$NO_COLOUR\$ "

homebrew=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin
export PATH=$homebrew:$PATH

export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:$PATH"
```

Any help much appreciated

Comment: what is your `echo $PATH` after opening new shell? did you tried telling RVM(it's part of RailsInstaller) to `rvm use 1.9.3`?

Comment: Thanks for suggestions - to anyone interested I just did a full reinstall of the OS and all software and it's working perfectly. Extreme but I figured having already spent a few days on this 2 hours of reinstalls was worth it.

Comment: For anyone in the same position, this guide is flawless http://blog.dean.io/posts/setting-up-a-ruby-on-rails-development-environment-on-mountain-lion

Answer (score 0):

Try 'rvm get head && rvm reload && rvm install 1.9.3 && rvm use 1.9.3'.